# Refer activity layout from another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have been developing web apps for a few years now, and just decided to start my way with android development using this book: Beginning Android Application Development of wrox.

At some point the book explains how to get a result from an intent (under the title "Returning results from an intent").

These are the steps:

1. The book describes how to change the main.xml layout file by adding some new controls.
2. The book describes how to change the activity that will be the second one (​Activity2),  it says that this activity should refer to the layout of a different activity by calling 
   `​Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);`
   since `btn_OK` was defined in the layout of the main activity (and not the one of ​Activity2, it is in `main.xml`) the method returns null.

The official documentation describes:

```
public View findViewById (int id)
Since: API Level 1
```

Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

So am I missing something here or is this book incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Using findViewById() in an Activity searches in the layout xml file that was used in setContentView() in onCreate().

If the two activities use different layout.xml files the button inside those files may have the same id and will not be confused (by findViewById()).

Answer (score 0):

In Activity1

```
public static Button btn;
void onCreate(...) {
   btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_OK);
}
```

In Activity2:

```
​Button btn = Activity1.btn;
```

Note: when you use Intent to navigate to Activity2, do not call activity1.finish(), as this will destroy btn;